# Unity 2D: Destroy + Instantiate new GameObject vs Changing state and sprite

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am creating prefabs for farmland in my 2D game. Since I want all ground tiles to turn into farmable-land when hit with a hoe, I am worried about performance (Since there will be hundreds of these GameObjects in a scene).

Would the best thing be to Destroy the ground tile and Instantiate a farm tile in it's position, or would it be better to create a more generic Script that is attached to every Ground tile(?), which has states like:

```
GROUND, FARMABLE, PLANTED
```

, then depending on the state I  change behaviour and set a sprite like: `tile.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(pathToSprite);`

Maybe I'm missing a better option but these are the ones I can think of.

Comment: Please let me know why you downvote? I'm new here, not sure what is wrong with this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroyin and instantiating hundreds of game objects during runtime is a recipe for disaster, memory fragmentation and GC going wild which will kill performance.

The second solution is way better. Use an `enum` for all the possible states of a tile in your game logic, and then change the `Sprite` field of the `Sprite Renderer` component accordingly.

PSA: Don't use `GetComponent` and `Resources.Load` every time you need to change a sprite, get a reference to the `Sprite Renderer` component and to a `Sprite[]` array which contains all possible state images to use in `Awake`, and then use those references to change the sprite image when needed.

Edit: Answering your question in the comment.

- Be sure that the `Sprites` are all in the `Resources` folder of your
  project, they can be in a subfolder, i.e.: `Resources/Sprites`.
- Check that the `path` string is correct, i.e. if the sprite asset is called `Circle`, and it's in the `Resources/Sprites` folder,
  `path` must be `"Sprites/Circle"`.

Code example:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

    Sprite[] spritesArray = new Sprite[10];

    void Awake() {
        spritesArray[0] = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Circle");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to call `cachedSprites[0] = Resources.Load<Sprite>("path");` in Start() I get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: I Initiate the Array like: `private Sprite[] cachedSprites`, am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks. It also worked to make it public and drag/drop sprites from resources in editor.

Comment: Yes, clearly you can expose the array via `public` or `[SerializeField] private` and assign references via Inspector.

Answer (score -2):

Try This:{ tile.GetComponent(/).sprite = Resources.Load(pathtosprite);    }

Comment: Ok Please Explain the question clearly because people like me wouldnt understand what that even means...

Comment: the question is clear enough.  you're answer is very low quality, I suggest you to delete it.